# Debugging dnx web project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-debugging, dnx

How does visual studio debug web project which runs using dnx? I use gulp-dnx plugin in my gulp task to run dnx with specific options, it executes dnx with web configuration and when I try to attach VS debugger to dnx process it doesn't automaticly load related pdb files and breakpoints don't work. But if I do this by clicking debug from vs it works fine.

I want to write extension for VS and gulp plugin which will make VS automaticly attach to dnx when my gulp task runs, but I can't find debug options Visual Studio uses to start debugging.

Comment: Are you sure you are attaching to the correct dnx? If so, have you tried to load symbols manually? Did it work? If you debug in VS you can show modules (Ctrl+Alt+U) and right click to see where VS looked for symbols. Finally `dnx` has the `--debug` switch if you use it the PID will be displayed and the process will be blocked until a debugger is attached.

Comment: Is there any Roslyn magic going on here? I mean, do you have to explicitly tell it write out PDBs to disk?